# Ctrl + a/e/f/b stopped working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

Usually, I use the following shortcuts on macOS:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>: Go to the beginning of the line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>: Go to the end of the line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>: Go to the next character
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>: Go to the previous character

Recently these shortcuts stopped working. I don't know why. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, some apps show nothing, some apps just show `a`. Is there any way to find out the reason and fix it?

**P.S.**: I'm sure <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> works because all other shortcuts with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you list some examples of app where you have been using the said shortcuts?

Comment: Can you check the output of `plutil -p /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Resources/StandardKeyBinding.dict | grep moveToBeginningOfParagraph` ?

Comment: @NimeshNeema These are several examples:

1. When I press `ctrl + a` in the address bar of chrome, I get `a`.
2. When I press `ctrl + a` in the system's built-in `Notes`, I also get `a`.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Here is the output of the command: `"^a" => "moveToBeginningOfParagraph:"
  "^A" => "moveToBeginningOfParagraphAndModifySelection:"
    1 => "moveToBeginningOfParagraph:"`

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using -- US. or something different?

Comment: @TomGewecke I'm using a US keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

Generally in MacOS, Cmd is used where Windows and Linux use Ctrl.  But it depends on the app.  You didn't say which app you are expecting these functions in.  In most macOS apps, Cmd-a is "select all" and Cmd-f is "find."

Comment: The OP's key combos work fine in such as TextEdit - they may not in Terminal-style apps

Comment: The shortcuts listed by OP work in all native text fields/view by default. They're EMACS-style navigation keybindings.

Comment: More info about those keybindings here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html